# Multiple Nested Class on LESS

Tags: css, html, less, stylesheet

I've searched arround the google and internet, also in this forum.
I just wondering is there any problem if I using multiple nested class in LESS stylesheet?

i.e:

```
#main-menu{
    height:50px;
    overflow:visible;
    background-color: @main_green;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:5px solid darken(@main_green, 10%);
    .border-radius(0);

    .nav{
        > li{
            > a{
                color:#FFFFFF;
                padding:12px 20px 13px;
                border-right:1px solid darken(@main_green, 10%);
                .transition(all .09s ease);

                &:hover,
                &:focus{
                    background-color:darken(@main_green, 5%);
                    padding:13px 19px 17px 21px;
                    border-right-color:transparent;

                    .box-shadow(inset 1px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
                }
            }

            &.open > a{
                background-color:darken(@main_green, 5%);
                padding:13px 19px 16px 21px;
                border-right-color:transparent;

                .box-shadow(inset 1px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
            }

            &:first-child{
                > a{
                    border-left:1px solid darken(@main_green, 10%);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    .dropdown-menu{
        background-color:darken(@main_green,5%);
        border:none;
    }

}
```

The compile result is okay, no error raised.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all but watchout with nesting it too much, you might end up making your css selectors too specific. As example a style for a generic globally used element should not be unnecessary nested.

Also the following nesting can be combined as a single selector:

```
   &:first-child{
            > a{
                border-left:1px solid darken(@main_green, 10%);
            }
        }
```

Is the same as:

```
&:first-child > a{
    border-left:1px solid darken(@main_green, 10%);
}
```

So nesting is should be used when the parent has css properties, otherwise you can combine the selectors as shown above.

Comment: ah.... I've got it.
so I don't need to nested class if there's no different or some rules in the parent class. just make it as single selector instead.

Thank you very much..